# Problema com validação

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho esse input no `php`:

```
<input id="complement" class='input-without-icon' type="text" placeholder="Complemento/Referência" value='<?php echo $Menu->getAddressComplement() ?>' />
```

Passo o id dele para o `javascript` e via `ajax` envio para outro arquivo `php`,

```
if ($street === $streetOriginal && $town === $townOriginal && $complement === $complementOriginal) {
    $stmtSaveAddress = $conn->prepare("UPDATE address SET street = :street, number = :number, town = :town, complement =                                       :complement, city_id = (select city.city_id from city where city.link = :cityLink) WHERE address_id = :address");
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':street', $street);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':number', ($number <= 0 ? NULL : $number));
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':town', $town);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':complement', $complement);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':cityLink', $city);
    $stmtSaveAddress->bindValue(':address', $addressId);

    echo'rua: '.$street;
    echo'number: '.$number;
    echo'bairro: '.$town;
    echo'complement: '.$complement;
    echo'cityLink: '.$city;
    echo'complemento original: '.$complementOriginal;
    echo'complemento: '.$complement;
        if ($stmtSaveAddress->execute()) {
            echo 'trueaddress';
        } else {
            if ($townOriginal != $town) {
                echo 'town';
            }
            if ($streetOriginal != $street) {
                echo 'street';
            }
            if ($complementOriginal != $complement) {
                echo 'complement';
            }
        }
}
```

Faço exatamente a mesma coisa para `street`, `town` e `complement`, mas estou com problema apenas no `complement`. Eu verifico se tem palavrão se tiver ele cai no `else`, se não ele executa. O que será que pode ser? Dei `echo` nas variáveis e estão todas como deveriam estar.

Aqui corrijo os palavrões:

`$obs = correctBadWords($obsOriginal);
    $history = correctBadWords($historyOriginal);
    $town = correctBadWords($townOriginal);
    $complement = correctBadWords($complementOriginal);
    $street = correctBadWords($streetOriginal);
    $name = correctBadWords($nameOriginal);`

Comment: Parece que tem uma chave (`}`) sobrando no 2º if... Dá uma conferida...

Comment: @MagicHat realmente estava sobrando, obrigada.. Mas não resolveu..

Comment: Ana, sua descrição não condiz com o código, onde exatamente está verificando se tem palavrão? Antes de fazer essa verificação, o conteúdo está vindo corretamente? Se sim, poste o código que faz essa verificação....

Comment: @KennyRafael Acrescentei ao código aonde valido meus palavrões. Ele na verdade corrige a variável.

Comment: tem o código dessa função? antes de passar por ela está tudo ok, certo?